# Rails has and belongs to many duplicate entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have 2 models and a join table('email_addresses_mailable_events'). Database being used is Postgres.

```
class MailableEvent < ApplicationRecord
   has_and_belongs_to_many :email_addresses
end

class EmailAddress < ApplicationRecord
   has_and_belongs_to_many :mailable_events
   validates :address, uniqueness: true
end
```

Suppose there are two unsaved records, { serial_number: '123', mark: 'Test' } with email addresses ['something@example.com', 'anything@example.com'] and another, {serial_number: '456', mark: 'Test' } with the same email addresses ['something@example.com', 'anything@example.com']

These are parsed from an xml file and I am saving these like

```
...
email_address_array.each do |address|
   @email_address_obj = EmailAddress.find_by_address(address)
    unless @email_address_obj   
       @mailable_event.email_addresses.new(address: address,unsubscribe: false)  
       @mailable_event.save
    else
       @mailable_event.save
       event_fk = @mailable_event.id
       email_fk = @email_address_obj.id
       sql_insert = "INSERT INTO email_addresses_mailable_events(\"mailable_event_id\", \"email_address_id\") VALUES(#{event_fk},#{email_fk});"
       ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql_insert)
end
```

Now the first one will be committed to the database tables as usual but while saving the second, I will look up the email addresses in database and associate the second MailableEvent record with those as follows :

```
> Look up first email address in email_addresses table and load it in.  # @email_address_obj = EmailAddress.find_by(address: 'something@gmail.com')

> Save the record({ serial number '456'}) associating it with 'something@example.com' too # @email_address_obj.mailable_events.create(@mailable_event.attributes)

> Look up second email address in EA table and load it in.  # @email_address_obj = EmailAddress.find_by(address: 'anything@example.com')

> Just associate the record({ serial number '456'}) with 'anything@example.com' # which means nothing has to be updated in Models and only a new entry { id: 'xx', EE_FK: 'xx', EA_FK: 'xx' } in join table has to be inserted, for which I cannot use @ea_object.mailable_events.create(@mailable_event.attributes) coz it will create a new duplicate EE record.
```

So, I solved this by inserting to join table using raw sql. But I am still surprised that Rails cannot handle this scenario. Is there a rails way to do it without having to use raw SQL?

Comment: Create a model for your join table, just like the others. Then run `EmailAddressesMailableEvent.create(email_address_id: 1, mailable_event_id: 1)`

Comment: @Iceman You mean using has_many :through?

Comment: Yeah, that would be much better yet. I didn't read it carefully enough, so i didn't want to provide an answer, just a comment.

Comment: @Iceman Can you take a closer look? Would be really helpful.

Comment: Pressed for time at this moment, but you should read this, it's all in there if you read it carefully. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html